# running pre-commit python package in Windows gives ExecutableNotFoundError: Executable `/bin/sh`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am working on a project where `pre-commit==2.15.0` was added to the python requirements file. I installed the requirements. Now when I try to do a `git commit` I get the following error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred: ExecutableNotFoundError: Executable `/bin/sh` not found
Check the log at C:\Users\username\.cache\pre-commit\pre-commit.log
```

In my pre-commit log I have:

```
pre-commit version: 2.15.0
sys.version:
    3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.executable: c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
os.name: nt
sys.platform: win32

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\error_handler.py", line 65, in error_handler
    yield
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\main.py", line 368, in main
    return hook_impl(
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\commands\hook_impl.py", line 231, in hook_impl
    retv, stdin = _run_legacy(hook_type, hook_dir, args)
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\commands\hook_impl.py", line 42, in _run_legacy
    cmd = normalize_cmd((legacy_hook, *args))
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\parse_shebang.py", line 82, in normalize_cmd
    exe = normexe(cmd[0])
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\parse_shebang.py", line 61, in normexe
    _error('not found')
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pre_commit\parse_shebang.py", line 51, in _error
    raise ExecutableNotFoundError(f'Executable `{orig}` {msg}')
pre_commit.parse_shebang.ExecutableNotFoundError: Executable `/bin/sh` not found
```

I work in Windows where my teammates work on Macs.

It looks like precommit is trying to reference the `/bin/sh` script which is not in Windows. How do I get this precommit working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your previous git hook is using a non-portable shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) (in your case this file will be located at `.git/hooks/pre-commit.legacy` -- originally `.git/hooks/pre-commit`)

if you adjust the tool to use `#!/usr/bin/env sh` then pre-commit will be able to run it (even on windows)

alternatively, if you don't want to use `pre-commit` in migration mode run `pre-commit install --force`

you're also using an outdated version of `pre-commit` which may be contributing to your issues -- so I'd recommend upgrading that was well

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: Hi @anthony-sottile, we are using 2.20.0, in 2022 dec we are seeing the similar issue. While running pre-commit it says Executable '/bin/sh' not found.
We have tried above solution, I am wondering is there a new solution here?

Comment: if it says `/bin/sh` and you have changed it to `/usr/bin/env sh` then you haven't changed all of them / in the right spot -- keep looking